# How to integrate Jquery with PHP

Tags: javascript, jquery

when i mouse over the HTML button didn't happen anything, what i expect is if i mouse over the button  it should show javascript working fine. Is there any way to achieve this. I new to javascript so the code may be wrong.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>JavaScript</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(e) {

                $(".carts").mouseover(function(){
                    $(".minicart").css("display","block");
                });

                $(".carts").mouseleave(function(e) {
                    $(".minicart").css("display","none"); 
                });
            }
    </script>

    </head>
    <body>

    <button class="carts"> Add </button>
    <div style="width:400px;position:absolute;top: 34px;right: 166px;z-index: 99999; background-color:#FFFFFF; display:none" class="minicart">



    <?php
    $var = 7;

    if($var == 7)
    {
        echo "JavaScript works fine ";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Didn't Work";
    } 

    ?>

    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Doesn't look like you're including `jQuery` anywhere.

Comment: I need to achieve that mentioned above, by using JavaScript or jQuery.

Comment: You don't include jQuery and you don't use javascript but PHP to display this message... Put any text in your block, you don't need to use a condition... If you use a position:absolute, you should wrap your 2 elements in a common parent !! (don't use body tag) Too much things are missing in your code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<html>
    <head></head>
<body>

    <button class="carts"> Add </button>

    <div style="width:400px;position:absolute;top: 34px;right: 166px;z-index: 99999; background-color:#FFFFFF; display:none; border:1px solid black" class="minicart"></div>

    <!-- import jquery from google hosted libraries
        or you can download the latest jquery version
        and use it with your project
     -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>

        $(document).ready(function(){
            // bind events
            $(".carts").mouseover(function(){
                $(".minicart").css("display","block");

            });

            $(".carts").mouseleave(function(e) {
               $(".minicart").css("display","none"); 
            });
        });

    </script>
 <?php
    $var = 7;

    if($var == 7)
    {
        echo "JavaScript works fine ";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Didn't Work";
    } 

    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It works perfectly, can you add PHP function inside that above code, and call it via javascript.

Comment: @ Oli Soproni B It works fine.

Comment: It seems PHP code didn't work

Comment: Eventually problem has solved

Comment: @BeenaGates Sorry I missed the closing tag of the div

Comment: Can I ask you another question, related to this topic.

Comment: How to I automatically reload only specific div every seconds such as minicart

Answer (score 1):

You have used jQuery code and have probably not imported it. Write the below line within `<head>...</head>`

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**NOTE:** Make sure to write this line before you start writing your script i.e. before this,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(e) {

        $(".carts").mouseover(function(){
            $(".minicart").css("display","block");

        });

        $(".carts").mouseleave(function(e) {
           $(".minicart").css("display","none"); 
        });
    }
    </script>
```

**UPDATE:** To make sure jQuery is properly imported write,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert("jQuery is working!");
});
```

Comment: here is my updated code :

Comment: @BeenaGates you are using PHP along with the code, are you using any server for this?

Comment: I didn't use any server

Comment: You cannot execute PHP code without a server installed on your system. I suggest you follow this link http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_install.asp

Comment: I have xampp installed on my system

Answer (score 1):

You have used jquery, but i guess you didn't donwloaded the source code of jquery file and link to it. I will prefer to download the ***http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js***
to your desktop or whatever location you want
and then link to it with script tag

**Edit**: Do download the JS file to your system and then include it in your HTML using

```
<script src="D:\MyProject\myscripts.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

here i uploaded my updated code, didn't get any positive result. I would like to know, is there any wrong functions inside this code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>JavaScript</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">


    $(document).ready(function(e) {

    $(document).ready(function(){
        alert("jQuery is working!");
    });

        $(".carts").mouseover(function(){
            $(".minicart").css("display","block");

        });

        $(".carts").mouseleave(function(e) {
           $(".minicart").css("display","none"); 
        });
    }
    </script>

    </head>
    <body>

    <button class="carts"> Add </button>
    <div style="width:400px;position:absolute;top: 34px;right: 166px;z-index: 99999; background-color:#FFFFFF; display:none" class="minicart">

    <p> heehghgdhgdh</p>

    <?php
    $var = 7;

    if($var == 7)
    {
        echo "JavaScript works fine ";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Didn't Work";
    } 

    ?>

    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Gates, you need to add a closing tag of the div